# How to use sed to replace a whole line with another one with characters in it

Tags: linux, sed, text-editors, text-editing

The file contains the following on line 19

`send -- "old@example.com\r"`

I want to change the email so I thought and came up with this

```
sed -i.bak '19s/.*/send -- "new@example.com\r"/' ./a
```

it does change line 19 but what I get is

```
"end -- "new@example.com
```

What's going on wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslash is the escape character in `sed` patterns, so a *literal* carriage return is inserted. What you want is `\\r` - an escaped backslash followed by a literal `r`.

Comment: I think I need to get some sleep haha! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing a search and replace you could just change the 19th line:

```
sed '19c\send -- "new@example.com\\r"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making this more difficult than it needs to be - just change the email address, not the entire line.  To demonstrate:

```
$ echo 'send -- "old@example.com\r"'  | sed 's/old@example\.com/new@example.com/'
send -- "new@example.com\r"
```

BTW, you can optionally use the `g` (global) modifier at the end of the command `s///` command if the search pattern might occur more than once in a line, and/or the `i` (ignore case) modifier if you want a case insensitive search - e.g. to use both: `s/old@example\.com/new@example.com/ig`.

Anyway, your command would then look like this:

```
sed -i.bak '19s/old@example\.com/new@example.com/' ./a
```

If you didn't happen to know the exact line number to change, specify a regular expression as the line-address rather than a line number:

```
sed -i.bak '/^send.*old@example\.com/ s/old@example\.com/new@example.com/' ./a
```

It's even easier to change ALL occurrences of old@example.com in the file, just don't bother specifying an address and the substitution will happen on every line of the file.

```
sed -i.bak 's/old@example\.com/new@example.com/' ./a
```

Comment: The thing is sed can very easily get cryptic and hard to deal with, I was doing something else and this was just an obstacle that I wanted to overcome anyway possible but huge thanks for your help!